# pandas window by groupby function

Tags: pandas

I have a pd dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame({'day': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
              'A': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0,0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
              'B': [7, 8, 4, 3, 5, 6, 3, 1, 4, 5],})
```

I want to do a sliding window that as long as the value of a column is 1 find the max, as soon as the value changes to 0 find the max for those 0. here is a desired output:

```
pd.DataFrame({'day': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
               'A': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0,0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
               'B': [7, 8, 4, 3, 5, 6, 3, 1, 4, 5],
               'Output': [8, 8, 8, 6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 5, 5 ]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create consecutive groups by `A` by compare with shifted values and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), then pass to [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `max`:

```
df['Output'] = df.groupby(df.A.ne(df.A.shift()).cumsum())['B'].transform('max')
print (df)
   day  A  B  Output
0    1  1  7       8
1    2  1  8       8
2    3  1  4       8
3    4  0  3       6
4    5  0  5       6
5    6  0  6       6
6    7  1  3       3
7    8  1  1       3
8    9  0  4       5
9   10  0  5       5
```